# Disable long tap on cordova android app not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have wrote below code to disable the long tap in android cordova app but still I am able to see cut copy paste bar in app.

```
super.appView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a plugin for android? Basically cordova / phonegap app uses javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did what I want

```
super.appView.getView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```